# Custom UITableViewCell auto layout doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to implement a custom table cell using Auto Layout programmatically like below, but for some reason I didn't get the expected result.

**Expected**:

[image]

**Actual**:

[image]

My observation is:

- The cell height doesn't grow as the content grows, and content overflows;
- The `bar` element should be a vertical blue bar, but it's not properly showing up;
- Setting background colors on the UIView elements doesn't work at all for some reason.

Please share some pointers on what I did wrong. Thanks in advance

**UITableViewCell Code is below**:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

        self.infoContainer = [[UIView alloc] init];
        self.title = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.time = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.bar = [[UIView alloc] init];

        [self.infoContainer addSubview:self.bar];
        [self.infoContainer addSubview:self.title];
        [self.infoContainer addSubview:self.time];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.infoContainer];

        self.infoContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.time.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.bar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [self.infoContainer.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.leftAnchor constant:18].active = YES;
        [self.infoContainer.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.rightAnchor constant:-18].active = YES;
        [self.infoContainer.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.topAnchor constant:10].active = YES;
        self.infoContainer.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

        [self.bar.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.infoContainer.leftAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
        [self.bar.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.infoContainer.topAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
        [self.bar.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.infoContainer.bottomAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
        [self.bar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.infoContainer.heightAnchor].active = YES;
        [self.bar.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:10];
        self.bar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        [self.title.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.bar.rightAnchor constant:15].active = YES;
        [self.title.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.infoContainer.rightAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
        [self.title.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.infoContainer.topAnchor constant:0].active = YES;

        [self.time.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.title.leftAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
        [self.time.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.title.rightAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
        [self.time.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.title.bottomAnchor constant:10].active = YES;
    }

    return self;
}
```

and in the table view, I have:

```
self.recentView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.recentView.estimatedRowHeight = 64.0f;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Automatic height completely depends on hooking constraints properly from top to bottom , so you miss 2 constraints

1-

```
[self.infoContainer.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.bottomAnchor constant:10].active = YES;
```

2-

```
[self.time.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.infoContainer.bottomAnchor constant:10].active = YES;
```

---

**Tip :** If you set top & bottom constraints here

```
[self.bar.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.infoContainer.topAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
[self.bar.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.infoContainer.bottomAnchor constant:0].active = YES;
```

Then no need for

```
[self.bar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.infoContainer.heightAnchor].active = YES;
```